# add widget at variable position to a grid layout Qt

Tags: qt

In Qt, how can I add a widget(checkbox) to a grid layout in between the column number.
For Example:

```
QGridLayout *layout= new QGridLayout;
QCheckBox *ch1 = new QCheckBox(this);
QCheckBox *ch2 = new QCheckBox(this);
layout->addWidget(ch1,0,0); // adds the widget at position 0 row and 0 column(ok)
layout->addWidget(ch2,1,0); // adds the widget at position 1 row and 0 column(not ok)
```

However, I want the widget ch2 to be at a distance less than 1 Column (say 1 row and 0.2 of Column)
How can I do it?

(I basically want to add a sub-check box ch2 to a main checkbox ch1 (like we have sub-bullets in main bullets in MS Office / powerpoint)

Comment: Did you try to play wit alignment argument of `QGridLayout::addWidget()` function, setting it to `Qt::AlignLeft` and `Qt::AlignRight` for different check boxes?

Comment: Ya..Aligning them to left or right aligns to the extreme left or right. I want it to be just a few mm to the right as we do to mention sub-bullets to a main bullet.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, as that would defeat the purpose of columns.  But you could double the number of columns that set everything you currently have to span two columns, then set your new checkbox to start 1 column inwards relative to the other widgets, that would have the same visual effect.

Comment: Ya..but I have only one column ( like a vertical list). And to a list item, I want to add a sub-list. If I place it at (0,1), then its too far away. I want it to be shifted only by a small amount.

Comment: Then make two columns, but make the first column your offset amount, then set the main list to span both columns and your sub-list only the second column.

Comment: whats the function to add offset?

Comment: ?? Are you asking how to set the column width?

Comment: iam not sure how to go ahead to achieve the desired result..i want my sub list starting column to have an offset compared to main list

Comment: I can't explain this any more simply...  You can get the same effect by using one column and then using a fixed-width `QSpacerItem` alongside items in your sub-list.  That will visually offset them.

Comment: I believe you want to set the `margin on the widget to offset` or `padding on the column` if you want all the items in the column to be offset. Perhaps this could be set in the stylesheet.